# Eclipse Kepler not showing WildFly 9 and 10

Tags: wildfly-9, wildfly-10

Experts,I'm trying to add WildFly 9 and 10 to my Eclipse Kepler (version=4.3.2).
After googling, I made **Help>Eclipse Marketplace...>JBoss Tools 4.1.2.Final**.
But, there's neither WildFly 9 nor WildFly 10.
Can you please tell me what's missing ?.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wildfly 9 and 10 support was added in version 4.3.0 of the JBoss Tools, which target Eclipse Mars.1 (4.5.1) as a running platform : http://tools.jboss.org/documentation/whatsnew/jbosstools/4.3.0.Final.html.

Your best bet is therefore to move to a more recent version of Eclipse (latest being Eclipse Neon: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/neonr)

Comment: Thanks Dominique for your reply, but there's no solution to use Wildfly 9 and 10 on Eclipse Kepler ?. I mean I can't import properties from Eclipse Mars or Neonr to Kepler ?.

Comment: I cannot speak for the authors of JBoss Tools but all our attempts at trying to use a more recent JBoss Tools in Indigo were unsuccessful. This is actually why we are currently migrating all of our developer workstations to Eclipse Neon.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dominique for your responses.